# Unable to Populate Search Field in Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to search [www.oddschecker.com](http://www.oddschecker.com) using Python and Selenium (chromedriver) but am struggling to populate the search field with the search term.

The code below clicks the magnifying glass ok but the `send_keys` statement does not populate the expanded search box.

Can anyone see the issue?

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="top-menu"]/li[8]/ul/li[1]/span/span').click()

sleep(5)

driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/header/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/ul/li[8]/ul/li[1]/div/div/div/form/fieldset/input').send_keys('Bicep')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **xpath** is `brittle`, please use relative xpath. see below.
2. Use `explicit waits`.
3. Close modal pop up may appear sometime, may not appear sometime so better to wrap them inside try and except block.

**Code :**

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
driver.maximize_window()
#driver.implicitly_wait(30)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
driver.get("http://www.oddschecker.com/")
try:
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.js-close-class"))).click()
    print('Clicked on close button if it appears')
except:
    pass

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[starts-with(@data-ng-click,'NavSearchCtrl')]"))).click()
search = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "search-input")))
search.send_keys('Bicep', Keys.RETURN)
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Much appreciated.